# get value of overriden getter

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this;

```
function A(){}
Object.defineProperties(A.prototype,{
    'propName' : {
        'get' : function(){
            return 'hallo';
        },
        'set' : function( p ){
            console.log( 'setting...' );
        }
    }    
 });

function B(){
    A.call( this )
}
B.prototype = Object.create( new A(), {
    'propName' : {
        'get' : function(){
            //do something than call getter of parent prototype
        },
        'set' : function( p ){
            //do something than call setter of parent prototype
        },
    }
});
```

Is it possible to call the prototype of a getter or setter, if yes, how?

Grettings....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype, {
  'propName': {
    get: function () {
      var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(A.prototype, 'propName');
      var value = desc.get.call(this);
      return 'altered ' + value;
    }
  }
});
```